# Convert custom icon font to copy and paste-able entities

Tags: fonts, icon, sketch-app

Font Awesome has a cheatsheet where they've converted their icons into html entities that you can copy and paste right into Sketch (and other editing programs), that changes the type element to the icon you want (as long as you have the font installed). Demo:
http://recordit.co/Irr9HBpVPX

I'm wondering how to do this with my company's own custom font. We have an internal living style guide that has all of our custom icons as CSS content code (as pseudo element background images), but not as type. I'm wondering how to convert them to type-able content that I could just copy and paste in using our custom font in Sketch.

Any help appreciated – thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your CSS background images exist as vector drawings, or just pixel images?

A simple way to create icon fonts is via [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app/), but you will need SVG files of your icons. Icomoon will generate an icon font plus a `demo.html` file similar to FontAwesome.

Basically icon fonts are just like normal fonts, except that their 'letters' are mapped to Unicode IDs that are not accessible by a normal keyboard. However, they can be copy/pasted like any other letter.

Comment: Ah, so they're unicode. OK, so probably the best way to do this is to convert through icomoon then get the unicode letters that come with them, or to somehow convert CSS content code into unicode (not sure if that is even possible...). Thanks!

Comment: If you have an existing font file, you can import it to Icomoon and then export it right away, which will generate your cheatsheet. You don't need the new font, just the demo.html which will show your font mapping list.